# Uploading on edit, but receiving expected Hash (got Array) for param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm able to upload files through nested attributes, but I'm getting this error:

```
expected Hash (got Array) for param 'project_images_attributes/
```

I don't think it's from the uploading portion, but it's coming from this code:

```
<% @project.project_images.each do |pic| %> 
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :project_images, pic do |image_fields| %>
    <%= image_fields.label :_destroy, :class => "checkbox" do %>

    <div class="img-controller-exist-preview">
      <div class="img-controller-exist-img">
        <%= image_tag pic.photo.url(:thumb) %>
      </div>
      <div class="img-controller-exist-delete">
        <%= image_fields.check_box :_destroy %> <span>Delete</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

because, when I remove this, I'm able to upload new photos.

This allows users to delete existing images when they're editing.

This is my full form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @project, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

<%= f.simple_fields_for :project_images, ProjectImage.new, child_index: ProjectImage.new.object_id do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.label :photo, "Upload Photo" %>
  <%= ff.file_field :photo, multiple: true, name: "project[project_images_attributes][][photo]" %>
<% end %>

<% @project.project_images.each do |pic| %> 
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :project_images, pic do |image_fields| %>
    <%= image_fields.label :_destroy, :class => "checkbox" do %>

    <div class="img-controller-exist-preview">
      <div class="img-controller-exist-img">
        <%= image_tag pic.photo.url(:thumb) %>
      </div>
      <div class="img-controller-exist-delete">
        <%= image_fields.check_box :_destroy %> <span>Delete</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I tested editing the project and uploading an image to add, and I get the error. But if I don't upload anything, editing works. I can delete photos and stuff, but this error occurs only when I try to upload something.

ProjectImage model:

```
class ProjectImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project

  paperclip_opts = {
    :styles => { :large => "800x800>", :medium => "x430>", :frontpage_thumb => "130x95#", :thumb => "150x150#" }, 
    :convert_options => { :all => "-quality 75 -strip" }
  }

  has_attached_file :photo, paperclip_opts
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

Project model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_images, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_images, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Controller:

```
def edit
  @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])

end
def update
  @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.update(project_params)

      if params[:photos]
        params[:photos].each { |image|
          @project.project_images.create(photo: image)
        }
      end     

      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please show us `project` model, and a related controller.

Comment: @Зелёный hi there! I've edited with model and controller

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :project_images, pic do |image_fields| %>
```

[***`fields_for`***](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for)(or `simple_fields_for` as you are using `simple_form_for`) expects a `hash` as a third argument(options) but you are passing an `array`.

Comment: So should I just take this out? Am I able to delete photos if necessary? I did this loop because I thought I could destroy the photos on checkbox

Comment: @hellomello I'm still thinking of that part:)

Comment: lol this would normally be the way to get the images that needs to be destroyed right? Unless there's another alternative... but there has to be!